# How can I set alpha color on Robocode?

Tags: java, colors, robocode

I built a robot in Robocode and I want it to have custom colors, more specifically using RGBA.

Is that possible?

I tried:

```
setBodyColor(Color.fromArgb(150, 0, 150));

setBodyColor(Color(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f));
```

But neither worked. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are programming with java:

Check this page in the API doc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#Color(int, int, int, int)

Try something like this (change the values):

```
int r = 25;
int g = 25;
int r = 25;
int a = 100;
robot.setBodyColor(new java.awt.Color(r,g,b,a));
```

Comment: The code works, but I guess robocode doesn't support transparency, which was what I was trying to achieve... Thank you anyways, it was useful!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

Add method:

```
private Color Color(int r, int g, int b, int a) {
    return new Color(r, g, b, a);
}
```

And then call it:

```
setBodyColor(Color(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
```